# Adding table td on 4th tr dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a `td` dynamically on 4th `tr` 3rd `table` of the inside the `<div>` element, but it's not adding.

**My code is:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table>tbody>tr>tr>tr>tr>div>table>tbody>tr>").each(function() {
    var code_cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");
    var cell = "<td>Hey I am Added here</td>";
    code_cell.before(cell);
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        1st tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        2nd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3rd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        4th tr and it's td
        <span>
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      4th tr first table tr and it's td
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 1st table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                      </td>
                      <td> </td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>

              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      4th tr second table tr and it's td
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td >
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 2nd table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                          &nbsp;
                      </td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>
              </span>
        <div>
          <table width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  4th tr table tr 3rd table tr and it's td
                  <b>Dynamically Add here instead of it</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <b>This is fixed td</b>
                </td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>

              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Could you please through me right direction to achieve the above functionality.

Comment: That selector is all kinds of wrong. The `>` selector is the "child" selector.

Comment: @Turnip any help on this?

Comment: `$('table tr:eq(4)').append(...)`. Also, your html is not valid. `<table>` inside `<span>` is not allowed

Comment: @Rajesh Yes I tried it but as my table structure 4th row 3rd table. So it's not applying.

Comment: What ever selector you come up with going to be incredibly brittle. Any change to your markup could break it. Can't you add an ID to the table you wish to target?

Comment: I think the real question is why are you using so many nested tables, tables should be used for tabular data only and this level of nesting points to something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your selectors. `>` is used to find children and not siblings. Try using `:nth-child()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) div > table > tbody > tr ").each(function() {
    var code_cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");
    var cell = "<td>Hey I am Added here</td>";
    code_cell.before(cell);
    // If you're trying to replace the existing td, use the below
    // code_cell.html(cell);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        1st tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        2nd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3rd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        4th tr and it's td
        <span>
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      4th tr first table tr and it's td
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 1st table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                      </td>
                      <td> </td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>

              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      4th tr second table tr and it's td
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td >
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 2nd table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                          &nbsp;
                      </td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>
              </span>
        <div>
          <table width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  4th tr table tr 3rd table tr and it's td
                  <b>Dynamically Add here instead of it</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <b>This is fixed td</b>
                </td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>

              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the correct hierarchy for selection.

```
$("table>tbody tr:gt(3) table:gt(2) tr").each(function() {
                var code_cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");
                var cell = "<td>Hey I am Added here</td>";
                code_cell.before(cell);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to have right interpreted what `4th tr 3rd table` means, but, did you already try this expression `$('tr div table').parent()` ?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var target = $('tr div table').parent();
  var content = '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
  
  target.html(content)
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) { background: yellow; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: pink; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        1st tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        2nd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3rd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        4th tr and it's td
        <span>
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      4th tr first table tr and it's td
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 1st table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                      </td>
                      <td> </td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>

              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      4th tr second table tr and it's td
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td >
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 2nd table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                          &nbsp;
                      </td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>
              </span>
        <div>
          <table width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  4th tr table tr 3rd table tr and it's td
                  <b>Dynamically Add here instead of it</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <b>This is fixed td</b>
                </td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>

              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`The problem is your selector is wrong`. You can use css `nth-child property` ( Refer this  [link for details](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)) to use it in a selector like the following [codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/GjXBwy) or this [codepen link 2](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/NRLBJE) if wanted to add it where the text "Dynamically add here.... " is written.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table tbody tr:nth-child(4) div > table > tbody > tr ").each(function() {
    var code_cell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");
    var cell = "<td>Hey I am Added here</td>";
    code_cell.before(cell);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #ddd; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #aaa; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        1st tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        2nd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        3rd tr and it's td
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        4th tr and it's td
        <span>
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      <th></th>
                      4th tr first table tr and it's td
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 1st table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                      </td>
                      <td> </td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>

              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      4th tr second table tr and it's td
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                      <th ></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td >
                          <table style="width:100%">
                              <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                      <td>
                                          4th tr table tr 2nd table tr and it's td
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </tbody>
                          </table>
                          &nbsp;
                      </td>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td >

                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
              </table>
              <br>
              </span>
        <div>
          <table width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  4th tr table tr 3rd table tr and it's td
                  <b>Dynamically Add here instead of it</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <b>This is fixed td</b>
                </td>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>

              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>

              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```